# validar numeros telefonicos en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, validación

buenas, como puedo validar números telefónicos en `c#` pero que este solo reconozca números y () - en su respectivo formato?
tengo el siguiente código para validar numero pero no para lo anterior.

```
if (Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))//Si es número
   {
      e.Handled = false;
   }
   else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)//si es tecla borrar
   {
      e.Handled = false;
   }
   else //Si es otra tecla cancelamos
   {
      e.Handled = true;
   }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es "*su respectivo formato*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día, una opción es la de solo aceptar números y cuando lo vayas a guardar darle el formato de la siguiente manera:

```
string telefono = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", 8005551212);
```

Para saber más sobre formatos que le puedes dar a un string tienes esta [página](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Otra opción es utilizar `MaskedTextBox`, al cual se asignas en la propiedad Mask el formato que quieres que tenga tu entrada, [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx) encontrarás información sobre como agregar una máscara. Aquí está el ejemplo de como agregar una máscara de un teléfono

```
MaskedTextBox mascara = new MaskedTextBox();
mascara.Mask = "(999)-000-0000";
```

Este es un control de Windows Forms, por tanto desde el desingner puedes poner la máscara.

Sí estás en Web, te recomiendo hacerlo por medio de JavaScript, aquí te dejo un [ejemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/dKRGE/3/).

La última opción es usar Regex, encontré una expresión que funciona según este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960596/example-of-a-regular-expression-in-jquery-for-phone-numbers).

```
"/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/"
```

Comment: oye disculpa la verdad nuna habia trabajado con maskedTextbox, lo use y soluciono mis problemas pero al momento "es para un numero telefonico" de que le doy aguardar en la bd, este lo manda en 0 , como se manda un maskedTextbox a la bd?

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió, bueno primero te recomiendo que valides por medio del .MaskFull sí se cumple el llenado de la información y después con la propiedad .Text obtienes el string de lo que hay en el control.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando la respuesta de @randall-sandoval, si no deseas usar *MaskedTextBox*, puedes utilizar un método con el patrón Regex que más te convenga como el siguiente y mandarlo llamar en el evento *Leave* de un *TextBox*:

//Clase estática Utilerias

```
    public static bool ValidarTelefonos7a10Digitos(string strNumber)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("\A[0-9]{7,10}\z");
        Match match = regex.Match(strNumber);

        if (match.Success)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

...
//Evento Leave de TelefonoTextBox

```
  if (Utilerias.ValidarTelefonos7a10Digitos(TelefonoTextBox.Text))
  {
          errorProvider2.SetError(TelefonoTextBox, "Debe capturar un teléfono de 7 a 10 digitos.");      
  }
```

Comment: El regex que publicaste está repitiendo el grupo, haciendo que no valide la cantidad de dígitos. De hecho, no es necesario usar siquiera el grupo. Se puede validar con `"\A[0-9]{7,10}\z"`. También, es innecesario comprobar si `.IsNullOrEmpty()`, ya que está siendo validado por el regex.

Comment: Disculpa @mariano, solo traté de ilustrar la forma de usarlo, ya edité la respuesta según tus sugerencias. Gracias

Comment: Excelente aporte, yo nunca he sido bueno en crear mis propias expresiones Regex, pero sí son muy útiles y es como lo más recomendado a la hora de validar, no solo números, sino también correos electrónicos y demás.

Answer (score 0):

Con el siguiente evento de la caja de Texto

```
private void TextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
if (!(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)) && (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back))
{
  MessageBox.Show("Solo se permiten numeros", "Advertencia",   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
  e.Handled = true;
  return;
 }
 }
```